# Find the previous occurrence of an element filtered by class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a php loop that print a lot of html in this form:

```
<div class="something">
  ...
  <img class="prod-img" src="What-I-Need"/>
</div>
<div class="buttons" data-description="Some text here...">
  <a class="activator">Click me!</a>
</div>
```

That piece of code is repeated many times. Usig jQuery I manage to get the description content using the parent selector just by:

```
$('.activator').click(function() {
  alert($(this).parents('.buttons').data('description'));
})
```

Since $(this) have a parent with the field I need, that js code is working great, I wonder now, how can I retrieve the src content of the class prod-img? since is outside the parent div...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are grouped like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="something">
      ...
      <img class="prod-img" src="What-I-Need"/>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons" data-description="Some text here...">
      <a class="activator">Click me!</a>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="container">
    .....etc....
```

You can get prod-img by using `.closest()` and `.find()`

```
var src = $(this).closest('.container').find('.prod-img').attr('src');
```

Otherwise you need to use `.parent()` `.prev()` and `.find()` which is very static making it harder to change the HTML markup without changing the code.

```
var src = $(this).parent().prev().find('.prod-img').attr('src');
```